# MSSQL showing null if a part of a string does not exist in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MSSQL and what I am doing is grabbing my description field which has a very very messy string and breaking it up into a new table in order to use some of the information. I have the entire thing working but on some of the string parts that are not consistent they do not show null they start back over at the beginning. 
Showing something like this: `cumented Verbal Warning ECR.**`

I am looking for help to be able to write something like if a certain string does not exist in the description to just show null.

This is what a description looks like but some of them do not have (Overage or shortage, $Amount Over/short, or Checkup/Balance Person):

```
**You are receiving a Documented Verbal Warning ECR.**

**ECR Category:** $100 or more, Over/Short
**Date of ECR Incident:** 2018-04-12
**Date of ECR Discovery:** 2018-04-12
**Location of ECR Incident:** Palma Sola
**Overage or Shortage:** Shortage
**$ Amount Over/Short:** 138.92
**Checkup/Balance Person:** Jennifer Brierton

**This is considered a serious event and has been reviewed by the CSAD Assistant Director and/or Director for appropriate action.**

**This is being considered your 1st Cash Handling Event.**

You must always strive to ensure a structured procedure is followed when counting, collecting, refunding, and depositing cash and/or checks. Cash handling is a critical part of our job; it is one of our Six Standards of Excellence and is taken into consideration during your Annual Performance Evaluation.

During the counseling session to review this ECR in the Managerâ€™s office, you will be provided the opportunity to make comments regarding this ECR. If you do not have any comments during the counseling session, you must respond stating, â€œI do not have any commentsâ€.

Any comments made by the Associate/Manager will be reviewed by the CSAD Director and an email will be sent to the Associate and Manager.


**Detailed description of incident**: On 04/12/2018 Michelle processed a title and registration transfer.  The total amount of the transaction was $154.35.  Michelle in error, ran the debit card for $15.43, therefore creating a shortage in the amount of $138.92.  The customer was contacted the same day and returned to pay the shortage.

**Actions you can take to avoid this incident in the future:** Stay focused. Maintain a solid routine. Spend a few extra seconds to double check while making change, counting back change, collecting, and depositing monies. Refer to CCARS-05 (Tips & Hints for Proper Cash Handling).

Per CCARS-11 it states the following: Enter the amount of the debit card transaction in the DEBIT CARD field **directly from the debit card receipt for the transaction.**  CCARS and the debit machine do not "talk" over any type of network; this will help ensure the accuracy of the transaction.
**BEST PRACTICE!** Hit the "Debit Card` button on the CCARS screen and (1) the system will display a message reminder to enter the amount from the debit card receipt and (2) automatically place the cursor in the debit field.

By following these steps, they serve as a safety net to ensure the correct amount is collected and entered in CCARS.
```

All the rest is fine thats why I am trying to just figure out a way to show null if it does not exist.

```
drop table #tempTable
create table #tempTable (id bigint, name varchar(100), submitter_id bigint, dscr varchar(3000));

insert into #tempTable 
select 
u.Id, u.Name, t.submitter_id, 
case when charindex('**Detailed description of incident', t.description) > 0 then 
substring(t.description, 1, charindex(char(10), t.description, charindex('**Detailed description of incident', t.description)) ) 
end 
from 
Users u 
join 
Tickets t on t.submitter_id = u.Id 
where 
t.created_at between '2017-11-01' and '2018-08-23' 
and ',' + t.tags + ',' like '%,' + 'ecr_administered' + ',%'

select id, name, submitter_id, 
substring(dscr, ectCatStart, charindex(char(10), dscr, ectCatStart) - ectCatStart + 1) EcrCategory, 
substring(dscr, dateOfEcr, charindex(char(10), dscr, dateOfEcr) - dateOfEcr + 1) DateOfEcrIncident, 
substring(dscr, dateOfDiscovery, charindex(char(10), dscr, dateOfDiscovery) - dateOfDiscovery + 1) DateOfEcrDiscovery, 
substring(dscr, location, charindex(char(10), dscr, location) - location + 1) LocationOfEcrIncident, 
substring(dscr, overShort, charindex(char(10), dscr, overShort) - overShort + 1) OverageOrShortage, 
substring(dscr, amount, charindex(char(10), dscr, amount) - amount + 1) Amount, 
substring(dscr, person, charindex(char(10), dscr, person) - person + 1) CheckupBalancePerson,
substring(dscr, ecrDescription, charindex(char(10), dscr, ecrDescription) - ecrDescription + 1) ecrDescription
from ( 
select id, name, submitter_id, 
charindex('**ECR Category:**', dscr) + len('**ECR Category:**') + 1 ectCatStart, 
charindex('**Date of ECR Incident:**', dscr) + len('**Date of ECR Incident:**') + 1 dateOfEcr, 
charindex('**Date of ECR Discovery:**', dscr) + len('**Date of ECR Discovery:**') + 1 dateOfDiscovery, 
charindex('**Location of ECR Incident:**', dscr) + len('**Location of ECR Incident:**') + 1 location, 
charindex('**Overage or Shortage:**', dscr) + len('**Overage or Shortage:**') + 1 overShort, 
charindex('**$ Amount Over/Short:**', dscr) + len('**$ Amount Over/Short:**') + 1 amount, 
charindex('**Checkup/Balance Person:**', dscr) + len('**Checkup/Balance Person:**') + 1 person, 
charindex('**Detailed description of incident**', dscr) + len('**Detailed description of incident**') + 1 ecrDescription, 
dscr 
from #tempTable 
) a
```

I am trying to figure out how to use CASE WHEN ... THEN NULL END construct
WHEN ... <-to put some condition, but I can't tell what condition I should put here

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense to me. Are you trying to find any of those three strings in a row? And for heaven's sake don't be scared to add some white space to your query. As posted it is just a wall of text. We need some sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you want to show NULL if any of those values does not exist, or if all of them do not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
(case when overShort > 0
      then substring(dscr, overShort, charindex(char(10), dscr, overShort) - overShort + 1)
 end) as OverageOrShortage,
```

`Charindex()` returns `0` when there is no match.  You seem to want to identify that case.

EDIT:

Use a `case` comparison:

```
select id, name, submitter_id, 
       substring(dscr, ectCatStart, charindex(char(10), dscr, ectCatStart) - ectCatStart + 1) as EcrCategory, 
       substring(dscr, dateOfEcr, charindex(char(10), dscr, dateOfEcr) - dateOfEcr + 1) as DateOfEcrIncident, 
       substring(dscr, dateOfDiscovery, charindex(char(10), dscr, dateOfDiscovery) - dateOfDiscovery + 1) as DateOfEcrDiscovery, 
       substring(dscr, location, charindex(char(10), dscr, location) - location + 1) as LocationOfEcrIncident, 
       (case when descr like '%**Overage or Shortage:**%'
             then substring(dscr, overShort, charindex(char(10), dscr, overShort) - overShort + 1)
        end) as OverageOrShortage, 
       substring(dscr, amount, charindex(char(10), dscr, amount) - amount + 1) Amount, 
       substring(dscr, person, charindex(char(10), dscr, person) - person + 1) as CheckupBalancePerson,
       substring(dscr, ecrDescription, charindex(char(10), dscr, ecrDescription) - ecrDescription + 1) as ecrDescription
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton . . . Duh.  You are adding more things to the `charindex()`, so it is no longer `0`.  Arrggh.  Just use `case` with `like`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:   `NULLIF([SomeColumn],REPLACE([SomeColumn],'String I want to check for',''))`

**Additional edit:**

Since you want to return NULL if any of the strings don't exist, you would have to nest REPLACE() functions for each string you want to test for.   Here's an example of testing for 3 different strings, returning NULL if any one of them are not present in `[Description]`:

```
NULLIF([Description],REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE([SomeColumn],'Test String 1','')
  ,'Test String 2','')
,'Test String 3','')
)
```